# wifi doesn't work in own apps, but works in blackberry's browser

Tags: blackberry, wifi

we have just started to write Blackberry apps and got strange situation. Our apps work with mobile internet (GPRS, 3G, EDGE) but are not working using wifi connection.

I have tried to change all the settings. But still usually it is just "Tunnel failure" or "connection timed out" errors. The same is with HTTPDemo example.

Could someone help and explain what it is with Blackberry and WiFi?

StreamConnection s = null;
                   s = (StreamConnection)Connector.open(getUrl() +";interface=wifi");
                   HttpConnection httpConn = (HttpConnection)s;

```
               int status = httpConn.getResponseCode();

               if (status == HttpConnection.HTTP_OK)
               {
                   // Is this html?
                   String contentType = httpConn.getHeaderField(HEADER_CONTENTTYPE);
                   boolean htmlContent = (contentType != null && contentType.startsWith(CONTENTTYPE_TEXTHTML));

                   InputStream input = s.openInputStream();

                   byte[] data = new byte[256];
                   int len = 0;
                   int size = 0;
                   StringBuffer raw = new StringBuffer();

                   while ( -1 != (len = input.read(data)) )
                   {
                       // Exit condition for the thread. An IOException is 
                       // thrown because of the call to  httpConn.close(), 
                       // causing the thread to terminate.
                       if ( _stop )
                       {
                           httpConn.close();
                           s.close();
                           input.close();
                       } 
                       raw.append(new String(data, 0, len));
                       size += len;    
                   }   

                   raw.insert(0, "bytes received]\n");
                   raw.insert(0, size);
                   raw.insert(0, '[');
                   content = raw.toString();

                   if ( htmlContent )
                   {
                       content = prepareData(raw.toString());                                
                   }     
                   input.close();                      
               } 
               else 
               {                            
                   content = "response code = " + status;
               }  
               s.close();                    
           } 
           catch (IOCancelledException e) 
           {       
               System.out.println(e.toString());                        
               return;
           }
           catch (IOException e) 
           {       
               errorDialog(e.toString());                        
               return;
           }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connecting the following way works for me

```
HttpConnection connection = null;
if (WLANInfo.getWLANState() == WLANInfo.WLAN_STATE_CONNECTED) {
         connection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url+ ";interface=wifi",
         Connector.READ_WRITE,true);
} else {
         connection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url+";deviceside=true", Connector.READ_WRITE,true);
}
```

Please refer the following resource for in-depth understanding and various methods.

[Sample HTTP Connection code and BIS-B Access](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Sample-HTTP-Connection-code-and-BIS-B-Access/td-p/653175) By peter_strange